# ansible jinja2 loop dictionary

Tags: ansible, jinja2

```
vars:
  openssh_match_config: 
      test:
        matchkey: 'User'
        matchvalue: 'XXX'
        chrootdirectory: '/home/%u'
        maxsessions: '2'
      test2:
        matchkey: 'Address'
        matchvalue: '1.3.0.3.0/24,192.43.120.0/27'
        maxsessions: '3'
        x11forwarding: 'yes'
        otheropt: VAL1
        otheropt2: VAL2
```

I need to have it translated as:

```
Match User XXX
   ChrootDirectory /home/%u
   MaxSessions 2
 
Match Address 1.3.0.3.0/24,192.43.120.0/27
   MaxSessions 3
   X11Forwarding yes
   otheropt  VAL1
   otheropt2 VAL2
```

I've updated the loop , seems to be on the right track but still can't figure out how to fix it...

```
{% for k,v in openssh_match_config.items() %}
Match {{ openssh_match_config[k]['matchkey'] }} {{ openssh_match_config[k]['matchvalue'] }}
  {%for x in v.items() %}
   {{x}}
  {%endfor%}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is `for x in v.items()`. The `items()` method returns a list of `(key, value)` tuples.  That is, given the following dictionary in variable `myvar`:

```
{"name": "bob"}
```

Writing `myvar.items()` would return `[("name", "bob")]`.

All this means that in your list, the value of `x` is a tuple, so writing `{{x}}` will get you the string representation of a tuple: something like `('matchkey', 'Address')`.

You could write something like this:

```
{% for k,v in openssh_match_config.items() %}
Match {{ v.matchkey }} {{ v.matchvalue }}
{% for optname, optval in v.items() %}
  {{ optname }} {{ optval }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Which gets you:

```
Match User XXX
  matchkey User
  matchvalue XXX
  chrootdirectory /home/%u
  maxsessions 2
Match Address 1.3.0.3.0/24,192.43.120.0/27
  matchkey Address
  matchvalue 1.3.0.3.0/24,192.43.120.0/27
  maxsessions 3
  x11forwarding yes
  otheropt VAL1
  otheropt2 VAL2
```

And that almost works, except for the erroneous conclusion of `matchkey` and `matchvalue`. You can avoid those by using appropriate conditionals:

```
{% for k,v in openssh_match_config.items() %}
Match {{ v.matchkey }} {{ v.matchvalue }}
{% for optname, optval in v.items() if optname not in ['matchkey', 'matchvalue'] %}
  {{ optname }} {{ optval }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Which produces:

```
Match User XXX
  chrootdirectory /home/%u
  maxsessions 2
Match Address 1.3.0.3.0/24,192.43.120.0/27
  maxsessions 3
  x11forwarding yes
  otheropt VAL1
  otheropt2 VAL2
```

Or you could redesign your data structure so that the ssh config values are kept separate from the metadata you use in your playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    openssh_match_config:
      - matchkey: 'User'
        matchvalue: 'XXX'
        config:
          chrootdirectory: '/home/%u'
          maxsessions: '2'
      - matchkey: 'Address'
        matchvalue: '1.3.0.3.0/24,192.43.120.0/27'
        maxsessions: '3'
        config:
          x11forwarding: 'yes'
          otheropt: VAL1
          otheropt2: VAL2
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: out.txt
        content: |
          {% for v in openssh_match_config %}
          Match {{ v.matchkey }} {{ v.matchvalue }}
          {% for optname, optval in v.config.items() %}
            {{ optname }} {{ optval }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks, I prefer the 1st variant "if optname not in ". + bonus indeed very nice explained :)